# Unable to make list blob request (windows azure)?

Tags: azure-storage

Unable to make list blob request using following URI with replacing myaccount with my storage account

http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your blob is public?
You can check is using CloudBerry Explorer a great free tool to manage Blobs.  You can download it here: http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-microsoft-azure-explorer.aspx

Once the application is install go on the container and right-click.  Go check in Properties is the security is public.